# kivy retrieving log file from clients android

Tags: android, kivy

I am working on android application which creates log files.

I want to retrieve log file of my application from client mobile to me in regular interval. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think scheduling a post with UrlRequest and Clock.schedule_interval would suit your need nicely, just put an http server somewhere to listen for these requests and store them.

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html